# Password Protection in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

I have a tool which calculates employees sales compensation. In Net Sales sheet which has employees along with their Sales Target, Profit, Bonus etc. Another sheet Password has passwords of each employee. Main Sheet which calculates the Sales Compensation by pulling in from Net Sales Sheet. The tool will be sent out to 100s of employees in the organization.  I don't want an employee for example A to calculate their colleague X sales compensation. So, at A1 cell they have to key in their Password and the rest of the sales compensation components are filled it.

Is there a better way to set up passwords in VBA.

Comment: No... and if you want this to be secure, do it in something other than Excel.

Comment: It would be much better to generate a workbook for each employee and send it to them.  It's trivial to crack an Excel password with a small amount of Googling.

Comment: Thank You! @BigBen

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion. @TimWilliams